# Unchecking an HTML checkbox using code

Tags: c#, html, checkbox, webbrowser-control

I am making a bot which has a WebBrowser control which loads some pages. There is a checkbox that I want to be unchecked by my bot. Right now I am using this code:

```
HtmlElementCollection elc = this.BotBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (HtmlElement el in elc)
{
    if (el.GetAttribute("value").Equals("Leishmania mexicana")) //to uncheck Leishmania mexicana checkbox
    {
        el.InvokeMember("click");

    }
}
```

But this seems not perfect because it sometimes re-checks the checkbox as this bot has to load pages and perform the task more than 100 times.

Here is the HTML tag of the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="jstree-real-checkbox" id="array(BlastDatabaseOrganism)" name="array(BlastDatabaseOrganism)" value="Leishmania mexicana" checked="checked">
```

Is there any way I can remove this attribute or set its **checked** attribute to null?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
el.SetAttribute("checked", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

first Import mshtml (Microsoft Html Object Library under com tab) namespace to your project. then use this

```
    using mshtml;


HtmlElementCollection elc = this.BotBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (HtmlElement el in elc)
{
      if (el.GetAttribute("value").Equals("Leishmania mexicana")) //to uncheck Leishmania mexicana checkbox
                    {
                            HTMLInputElement elm = el.DomElement as HTMLInputElement;
                          elm.@checked = false;

                    }
}
```

Comment: as far as  I know it is just a property

Comment: Well it do looks like a property ,is there any specific name to it or any link (like msdn) describing it further ,I will be thankful for that